# TinyMce editor issue in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tinymce, editor

I am facing a problem with TinyMce editor in google chrome. the editor is not wrapping up in this browser. all editing control lies in one line. is does not happen in other browsers. How to solve this issue? please any suggestions?

below is my coding for TinyMce

```
{literal}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{/literal}{$BASE_URL}{literal}js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            tinyMCE.init({
                mode : "textareas",
                editor_selector : "mceEditor",
                theme: "advanced",
                  plugins : "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
      theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
                // Theme options
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect",
            theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo",
            theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup",
            theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
            theme_advanced_buttons5: "link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
            theme_advanced_buttons6: "fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
            theme_advanced_resizing : true,

     template_external_list_url : "{/literal}{$BASE_URL}{literal}js/template_list.js",
            external_link_list_url : "{/literal}{$BASE_URL}{literal}js/link_list.js",
            external_image_list_url : "{/literal}{$BASE_URL}{literal}js/image_list.js",
            media_external_list_url : "{/literal}{$BASE_URL}{literal}js/media_list.js",

                height: "365px",
                width: "610px"



            });
        </script>
        {/literal}
```

Comment: I think its a bit hard without your code.

Comment: can you please post your full tinymce configuration

Comment: This is my coding for TinyMce

Answer (score 0):

### CSS

You can try with a CSS solution:

```
.mceEditor > table {
    width:/* my width */ !important;
}
```

and/or you could access the toolbar width directly with `.mceToolbar`

### Configuration

Or try adjusting your configuration by removing the `px` from the `height` and `width` settings:

```
{literal}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{/literal}{$BASE_URL}{literal}js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            tinyMCE.init({
                mode : "textareas",
                editor_selector : "mceEditor",
                theme: "advanced",
                  plugins : "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
      theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
                // Theme options
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect",
            theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo",
            theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup",
            theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
            theme_advanced_buttons5: "link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
            theme_advanced_buttons6: "fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
            theme_advanced_resizing : true,

     template_external_list_url : "{/literal}{$BASE_URL}{literal}js/template_list.js",
            external_link_list_url : "{/literal}{$BASE_URL}{literal}js/link_list.js",
            external_image_list_url : "{/literal}{$BASE_URL}{literal}js/image_list.js",
            media_external_list_url : "{/literal}{$BASE_URL}{literal}js/media_list.js",

                height: "365",
                width: "610"
            });
        </script>
        {/literal}
```

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:width